# spring-ws Generating SOAP Service without Request Parameter Suffix

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I need to use some XSDs files from an industry standard to generate a SOAP webservice from it. REST is not possible because the consumer is only able to do SOAP calls.

The parameters in the XSD are defined as the following:

```
   <xsd:element name="getData">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Request" type="CT_getDataRequest" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
   <xsd:element name="getDataResponse">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Response" type="CT_getDataResponse" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
```

That is my endpoint definition:

```
@Endpoint
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.machine-config.net/namespace/data";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getData")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetDataResponse getData(@RequestPayload GetData request) {
    }
}
```

Here is my WsConfiguration:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(messageDispatcherServlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataDefinition")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition dataWsdl11Definition() {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("dataServicePortType");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.machine-config.net/namespace");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(dataSchemas());
        
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSchema")
    public XsdSchemaCollection dataSchemas() {
        CommonsXsdSchemaCollection xsds = new CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(new ClassPathResource("xsd/data-2.18.1433.2.xsd"));
        xsds.setUriResolver(new DefaultURIResolver());
        xsds.setInline(true);
        return xsds;
    }
}
```

But inside the generated WSDL the following operation is generated:

```
<wsdl:operation name="getData">
    <wsdl:output message="sch0:getDataResponse" name="getDataResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

The `wsdl:input` part is missing.

When I change the xsd:element `getData` to `getDataRequest` the `wsdl:input` element is generated.
But that workaround will not work because the XSD will be delivered by a vendor and I am not allowed to change anything in this file.

How can I make spring-ws to recognize the input parameter without the Request Suffix?

Comment: Why is the definition the same as the wsdl? The definition doesn't have an input either. I have a feeling there is information missing here.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the questions. I pasted the wrong piece of code. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Can you show the full xsd? I assume you generate the classes based from this and not manually constructing them, finally how are you generating the WSDL?

Comment: The full XSD contains thousands of lines. Due to copyright I am not allowed to post this as a full file public. Which Information from the XSD to you need? The Java classes are generated with org.codehaus.mojo - jaxb2-maven-plugin. I added the WS Config part to the post.

Comment: You can try setting `requestSuffix` to `""` on the `DefaultWsdl11Definition ` as the default is `Request`. Also assuming you are using Spring Boot and a recent version, remove the `MessageDispatcherServlet`, the `@EnableWs` and `extends WsConfigurerAdapter` to allow Spring BOot to do auto configuration.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.7.15. If I remove the ````MessageDispatcherServlet```` Bean, the configuration does not work any longer. When I request the WSDL I get an 404 error. Setting ````requestSuffix```` to Space gives an error: ```` requestSuffix must not be empty````

Comment: You should also remove `@EnableWs` you only need the 2 beans, Spring BOot should configure the `MessageDispatcherServlet` then. It won't if you add `@EnableWs` and/or keep the `extends WsConfigurerAdapter`. If that gives a failure (which wouldn't be unexpected) you can try using the `ProviderBasedWsdl4jDefinition` instead, which might require some additional configuration.

Comment: I tried lots of things - but nothing worked. Removing ````@EnableWs```` and the ````MessageDispatcherServlet```` results in an error 404 when I try to access the WSDL or the method. Do you have an example of how to use ````ProviderBasedWsdl4jDefinition````?